# Xamarin.Forms TabbedPage

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, tabbedpage

I have a little problem in this project. This is my tabbed page declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JacksCurrencyConverter;assembly=JacksCurrencyConverter"
            x:Class="JacksCurrencyConverter.StartPage"
            x:Name="Children"
            HeightRequest="10" 
            WidthRequest="10">

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <local:MainPage Icon="currency.png"  Title="Exchange"/>
        <local:FavouritesPage Icon="favourites2.png"  Title="Favourites"/>
        <local:MainPage Icon="statistics2.png" Title="Info"/>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

Then this is how it looks in iOS and Android:

iOS:

[image: iOS]

Android:

[image: Android]

How could I reduce the empty blue space shown in the tabbpage on Android?

Blue space to reduce:

[image: Blue space to reduce]

Sorry, I need at least 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: Can you show me the code where you are calling this page's constructor?

Comment: @G.hakim
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new StartPage());
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this space is because you have a navigation page wrapped on your normal content page

Doing something like this will remove your space:

```
Mainpage= new StartPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add horizontal and vertical option and this should fix the top empty space.

```
 <TabbedPage>
     <ContentPage Title="Exchange" 
                  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                  VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="0">
         <local:MainPage Icon="currency.png"  Title="Exchange"/>
     </ContentPage>
     <ContentPage Title="Favourites" 
                  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                  VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="0">
          <local:FavouritesPage Icon="favourites2.png"  Title="Favourites"/>
     </ContentPage>
     <ContentPage Title="Info" 
                  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                  VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="0">
         <local:MainPage Icon="statistics2.png" Title="Info"/>
     </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: This throws the following error: No property, bindable property, or event found for 'HorizontalOptions', or mismatching type between value and property. (JacksCurrencyConverter)

Comment: can you try adding the horizontal and vertical option within <local: >

Answer (score 0):

You can add `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` to the TabbedPage tag in your XAML.

Then your code should look like this:

```
<TabbedPage
 xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JacksCurrencyConverter;assembly=JacksCurrencyConverter"
 x:Class="JacksCurrencyConverter.StartPage"
 x:Name="Children"
 HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="10"
 NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
...
```

Another way would be calling `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);` in the constructor or OnAppearing function of your Page.